# What's the hexagon symbol under the Sanctuary?

Tags: terra-mystica

In Terra Mystica, under most structures, you find the income that building generates. But, the Sanctuary *also* has a weird hexagon:

[image]

The gold outline looks just like those used on the town tokens. I couldn't find anything about it in the rules, looking under anything I could find related to the Sanctuary or towns (based on the shape). I don't see the image anywhere either.

It looks important. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a common enough question that there's a link directly to a thread about it on the game's [boardgamegeek page](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/120677/terra-mystica).

Short answer, quoted from one of those threads:
"It means you only need a minimum of 3 connected buildings instead of 4 when forming a town if the sanctuary is part of these structures."

Comment: And from [that thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/18158804#18158804), this actually _is_ in the rulebook, on page 14, in the "founding a town" section. It's even in a little highlighted box, with the icon and everything. Seems obvious in retrospect, but the rules are so full of boxes and notes and special sections that I'm not surprised I'm the only one who missed it.

Comment: Er, not surprised I'm *not* the only one. Whatever. :)

Comment: I actually got to use this answer last night, the first time I'd actually *played* TM in months, when another new player asked the precise question :)